# Append a class to an existing selected class (selected class statement has multiple classes selected) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm selecting multiple classes with one statement:

```js
 var sidebarList = document.getElementsByClassName("side-nav nav-links nav-item");
```

I'm trying to add a class called `open` to it:

```js
sidebarList.classList.add("open");
```

But I am getting this error `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` and I do not understand why.

This is the jquery equivalent of what I'm trying to do

```js
var sidebarList = $(".side-nav ul li");
sidebarList.addClass("open");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for selecting elements with multiple classnames as selector. After that you've to loop through your selected elements and add the class to each element.

```js
var sidebarList = document.querySelectorAll(".side-nav.nav-links.nav-item");

sidebarList.forEach(function(oItem){ 
  oItem.classList.add("open");
  console.log("Added class 'open' to list item");
});
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="side-nav nav-links nav-item" >Test</li>
<li class="side-nav nav-links nav-item" >Test</li>
<li class="side-nav nav-links nav-item" >Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

The result of document.getElementsByClassName() is a HTML Collection.
So you need to turn it from a HTMLCollection into an array. Then we can map over this.

```
var arrayOfSectionDividers = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("side-nav"))
arrayOfSectionDividers.map(element => element.classList.add("hidden"))

<ul>
<li class="side-nav nav-links nav-item" >Test</li>
<li class="side-nav nav-links nav-item" >Test</li>
<li class="side-nav nav-links nav-item" >Test</li>
</ul>
```

or if you prefer:

```
var matches = document.getElementsByClassName('side-nav');

for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
  matches[i].classList.add('hidden');
}
```

Comment: This is not a mapping task. And one does not need to cast the html collection into a JS array when one easily can use the `forEach` of a node list returned by `querySelectorAll`? Please consider editing or deleting your answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope ... please use the array's `forEach` instead of `map`, because there is nothing that needs to be mapped (the return value of  `element.classList.add("hidden")` is `undefined` anyhow).

Comment: Peter if you tested it s not undefined

Comment: My argument was that one should not use `map`. (1st) there is no reason of creating a new array (which one does using `map`) because one is going to add `for`-`Each` element's class-list a new value. (2nd) using `map` will return an array filled with just undefined values since the return value of a class-list's `add` method is `undefined`. Hope, this helps you in editing your answer.